# how to use ios tools like sliding in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to modify my ASP MVC 3 application behavior on iPad. For instance, instead of simple pagination, I want to use iPad's awesome sliding effect. But when I made some researches, I found out that's impossible to use IOS api elsewhere a native application.

So is there some workaround to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) can help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and nice tuto btw. But all this is about the animation, my question is how can I detect the event "sliding the screen with the finger" without using ios api.

Comment: I don't think you can use a native API in a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this using jQuery mobile, it's quite easy actually. Here is an example

```
<div id="listitem">Swipe Right and left</div>
<javascript type="text/javascript">

  $("#listitem").live("swiperight", function () {
    alert('right');
  });

  $("#listitem").live("swipeleft",function () {
    alert('left');
  });

</javascript>
```